# XLSX package in NodeJS generates empty numbers file

Tags: node.js, express, xlsx

I'm using XLSX package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to creating xlsx files. Everything works fine. Now I'm trying to do exactly the same thing but save file as .numbers .

According to documentation https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/write-options#supported-output-formats writing to numbers looks a little bit different but I did what they recommend.

```
 import XLSX_ZAHL_PAYLOAD from 'xlsx/dist/xlsx.zahl';
  save() {
    return XLSX.write(this.workbook, {
        type: 'buffer',
        bookType: 'numbers',
        numbers: XLSX_ZAHL_PAYLOAD,
        compression: true
    });
}
```

in console I get info:

```
The Numbers writer currently writes only the first table
The Numbers writer is currently limited to A1:J50
```

Files are being downloaded and when I click spacebar to see preview my data are there[image]

But when I open file by clicking on it, sheet is empty. To downloading files I'm using adm-zip package

```
const zip = new AdmZip();
zip.addFile('name', save());
const buffer = zip.toBuffer();
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

**Edit**
Thanks to @jonrsharpe comment I used newer version (0.20.0 from cdn  instead of 0.18.5 from npm) and everything works

Comment: FYI the version on npm is out of date, they no longer publish there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, I didn't notice that. I used newer version from cdn and it helped!